# BIRT Pie chart can grow property?

Tags: birt, pie-chart, autoresize

I have a pie chart using BIRT. Works fine but the problem is it only shows data that is "fitted" in the chart's size. Is there a "can grow" property equivalent for pie charts? I mean all data shows only if I resize the pie chart into larger one. But if I choose a larger amount of data, it won't fit again. I need the size to be "auto resize" according to how many data to be displayed.

I tried modifying the advanced settings but nothing worked

- Format - Overflow: Auto, Scroll and Visible
- Push down - set to true

I do not see any other properties related to pie chart formatting. Can anyone point me to right direction? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, found it [here](http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2008/04/birt-resizing-charts.html) but I tweaked it a bit. OnRender event of the chart itself type this:

```
function afterDataSetFilled(series, dataSet, icsc)
{

    if( series.getSeriesIdentifier() == "categorySeries" ){
        if( dataSet.getValues().length <= 4 ){
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setWidth(450);
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setHeight(250);
            }
        if( dataSet.getValues().length > 4 && dataSet.getValues().length < 8 ){
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setWidth(450);
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setHeight(400);
            }
        if( dataSet.getValues().length > 8 ){
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setWidth(450);
             icsc.getChartInstance().getBlock().getBounds().setHeight(600);
            }

        }
}
```

"categorySeries" is the title of the "simple series" type that can be found in "Format Chart" tab when chart is double clicked.

Comment: You should mark your answer as accpeted so that others will know you are no longer looking for help.